# How to calculate the cost of algorithm has infinite loop

Tags: performance, algorithm, recursion, infinite-loop, analysis

my algorithm has an intentional looping

the program repeat itself each time by recursive calling

so how can I explain the cost (cost analysis) of it ?

Comment: In terms of how long it runs depending on the input. Do you know about O(n) notation?

Comment: What is this loop/recursion exactly is? Is it really infinite? or is there any stop clause along the way. Also note, since it is recursive - your number of recursive calls cannot exceed the size of the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, processes that loop and don't take particular input, or produce particular output, are measured in terms of the rate at which they complete iterations. In games and media applications, it's common to talk about frames per second (FPS). In other embedded and real-time applications, cycle time can be an important performance metric. Higher-level metrics, such as "jobs per minute" or "maximum queue latency" can be important, as well.